# How do I use transport-http instead of wagon in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to use [maven-resolver-transport-http](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/maven-resolver-transport-http/index.html) in maven instead of the default wagon.
So far I just downloaded the jar and its dependencies and copied it in my `maven/3.8.4/libexec/lib` installation and it worked.
But I can't find the configuration to make that happen in a cleaner way.

Comment: Can you explain what you like to accomplish? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want maven to use the transport-http resolver instead of the wagon-http. My goal is to avoid http calls for `.sha1` files if the requested artifact has the Nexus ETag that contains it, and from what I've seen this is supported only by transport-http. (I tested with mitmproxy in between and I'm sure transport-http does the trick)

Comment: Simply question: Why ? What is the problem with sha1 ?

Comment: There's no problem. I just want to avoid one http call if I can. I want to know more about maven and how to use it. That plugin has been implemented and it works so, I assume, there must be a way for people to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since Maven 3.9.0](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html), the default resolver transport is "native http" (which is in fact `maven-resolver-transport-http`). So if you're using an older version, upgrade to 3.9.0 or later and it's not required to specify anything.

According to the [official guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html), since version 3.9.0 it's possible to configure the resolver transport with the flag `-Dmaven.resolver.transport` which accepts the following values:

- `default` - (implied if not present), does auto by default
- `native` - forces use of transport-http
- `wagon` - forces use of transport-wagon
- `auto` - delegates to the resolver the transport choice (using aether.priority. and related properties, or just relying on component priorities).

Just as an example, to explicitly tell Maven to use `maven-resolver-transport-http`, add the following flag to Maven: `-Dmaven.resolver.transport=native`.